# ASP.net Core: The browser could not find the action of the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a new simple controller But when I enter the following address in the browser, could not find it!

*http://localhost:5000/Test/Index*


Test.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Welcome");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I do the wrong thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first Edit your Controller attribute :

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```

to

```
[Route("[controller]")]
```

and

try this

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endPoints =>
            {
               endPoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  "default",
                  "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
```

also make sure you are using correct port 5000 or 5001 are defaults

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are using correct port number.

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your solution